# certificate verify failed: self signed certificate with keycloak after providing a valid self-signed certificate

Tags: python, flask, ssl, python-requests, keycloak

firstly, I have tried all the solutions provided in the other questions related to SSL verification but nothing works for my case, and let me put you in my context.

I have a keycloak instance version 16.1.1 deployed in a container with the config below:

```yaml
  keycloak-m1:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: codingpuss/keycloak-silicon:16.1.1
    restart: always
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      KEYCLOAK_EXTRA_ARGS="-Dkeycloak:profile:feature:upload_scripts=enabled":
      KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_FILE: /opt/keycloak/localhostCert.pem
      KC_HTTPS_CERTIFICATE_KEY_FILE: /opt/keycloak/localhostKey.pem
    ports:
     - "8090:8080"
     - "8843:8443"
    networks:
      - myNetwork
    volumes:
      - ./keycloak-data:/tmp
      - ./certs-folder/local:/opt/keycloak
```

I used this command to generate the SSL certificate and its key in order to deploy keycloak with HTTPS

```
openssl req -x509 -out localhostCert.pem -keyout localhostKey.pem \
 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 \
 -subj '/CN=localhost' -extensions EXT -config <( \
  printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

After that I set the **localhostCert.pem** in a directory and processed it with **c_rehash** utility supplied with OpenSSL as explained in the  [docs of requests package](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification).

Then I referenced that package in the **verify** parameter in the request but it keeps failing to verify the certificate.

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8843): Max retries exceeded with url: /auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1002)')))
```

Here is the python code I used:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {
        constants.GRANT_TYPE_KEY: constants.OAUTH_PASSWORD_FLOW,
        constants.USERNAME_KEY: "test",
        constants.PASSWORD_KEY: "test",
        constants.CLIENT_ID_KEY: "test-client",
        constants.CLIENT_SECRET_KEY: "QX1hsAGiQADuegPcAXOn4mlwZUfcoksH"
    }
    session = Session()
    oauth_request = Request()
    oauth_request.method = "POST"
    oauth_request.url = "https://localhost:8843/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/token"
    oauth_request.data = data
    session.verify = "<path_to_the_certs_directory>"
    response = session.send(oauth_request.prepare())
    access_token = response.json().get(constants.ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, None)
    print(access_token)
```

In the other side i used the same **localhostCert.pem** and **localhostKey.pem** to deploy a flask API with HTTPS and consume it with requests using the same method and referencing the folder of cert, and it works well, the requests module is able to verify the certificate.

Here is the code I used to deploy the flask api with https:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import ssl
app = Flask(__name__)

context = ssl.SSLContext()
context.load_cert_chain('localhostCert.pem', 'localhostKey.pem')
@app.route('/test/', methods=['GET'])
def get_test():
    return jsonify(test="test")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001, debug=True, ssl_context=context)
```

My question is why SSL cert is verified when used in a flask API and not with keycloak ? And how to make it work with it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In order for a self-signed certificate to be usable with the `verify` parameter in request it needs to be a CA certificate, i.e. basic constraints must contain CA:true (this was at least true in openssl versions before 3.0). This is not the case with the generated certificate:
...
X509v3 extensions:
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
DNS:localhost
X509v3 Key Usage:
Digital Signature
X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
TLS Web Server Authentication
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
...

To fix this one needs to add `basicContraints=CA:true` to the existing configuration and also `keyCertSign` to the keyUsage (since this is needed for a CA):

```
openssl req -x509 -out localhostCert.pem -keyout localhostKey.pem \
 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 \
 -subj '/CN=localhost' -extensions EXT -config <( \
  printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nbasicConstraints=critical,CA:true\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature,keyCertSign\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

Comment: I have generated a cert and key with the command you have provided, but it gives the same error (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate (_ssl.c:1002)')))

Comment: @AbdelYsf: does not happen to me when using `requests.get(url, verify=path_to_self_signed_certificate)`. I recommend that you try this instead of using the directory in the hope that the certificate gets found there. It's one thing less which can go wrong.